# How to copy ssh keys on a new VM

Tags: ssh, chef

I have the following situation:

-new CentOS6 VM (created within a Hyper-v failover cluster), joined Windows AD via script

I need to bootstrap this new VM in chef server and to deploy an application via chef recipe with jenkins, using a service account. The normal way (without Chef), I would deploy the application with a Jenkins job, but in order to do that, I would need to copy jenkins's public key in the VM's service account user's authorized_keys via ssh-copy-id.

I would need to do that when I create the VM, either using a chef recipe or somehow in the powershell script (which creates the machine) or some other way.

Comment: The only way to be able to achieve this with the PowerShell would be, if the partitions withing the VHDX were FAT or NTFS. That's mostly not the case (so I would also remove the category `powershell` from the question). :)

Comment: I can't use a FAT or NTFS partition, but I think that i'll add the public key of that user in the template. so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the chef [authorised keys](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh_authorized_keys) cookbook to deploy your public key.

```
ssh_authorize_key 'service@acme.com' do
  key 'AAAA[...]'
  user 'root'
end
```

If you want to set a private key so that you can open a connection to the VM that has that public key then you can use the [ssh-private-keys](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssh-private-keys) cookbook.

The private key would need to be stored in an encrypted data bag.

```
ssh_private_key 'key1'
```

would retrieve a private key from the encrypted data bag with the id key1